# Next.JS app in ECS does not load env variables nor credentials

Tags: next.js, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, aws-credentials

I am migrating from Vercel to AWS, and I'm trying to run my app with ECS using ECR.
The problem es that the environment variables defined in the ECS are not found in runtime, and if I run a query to an AWS Service, it doesn't recognize the role neither. If I set the environment variables in the github actions workflow and include `RUN printenv > .env.production` before the `RUN npm run build` in my Dockerfile, it does find the environment variables, and of course I do not like the solution.

My Dockerfile is something like this:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN printenv > .env.production

RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

This solves the environment variables problem, but I couldn't find a solution for the permissions, as of course I don't want to add the access keys in this way. The error is "Could not load credentials from any providers", so is not a problem that the policy does not have a permission, it does not inherit the role from the ECS.

Comment: There are multiple roles for ECS tasks. The role that the AWS SDK (or CLI tool) would pick up automatically from ECS is the ECS Task Role (not the task execution role). The task role is optional. Make sure you are adding an ECS Task role to your task. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

Comment: As for the environment variables, I believe Next.js reads those at build time, not run time, and build time happens in your Dockerfile when you are creating the image. So it is too late to set those once you are creating containers from the image.

Comment: thank you for the comments. Regarding the roles, I modified the one for the task role, I also tried modifying the task execution role, and the problem persists. And the role is mandatory, so if my policy is not right, or the role does not have any policy, de error should be Access Denied.

As for the environment variables, I understand that it can have some in runtime, but I may be wrong.

Comment: The task execution role will not be used by your code. Only the task role will be made available to your code to use, and that role is optional, not mandatory.

Comment: thanks for that, I didn't know that was optional. Anyway, I have set both, and I still have this error as if there was none set. I did this with terraform, and I have another app running with the same modules which is working perfectly, the difference is that is not using next.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tries, I found out that my problem was because the nextjs output was set as `standalone` as nextjs documentaciones recommends. But this is for apps that are 100% statics, in my case where I use environments that are configured in ECS or where I have api routes that need to use the assume role it was useless.

I had to remove the output from next.config.js, and add more files / folders in my Dockerfile so they are copied to the container in ECR. My Dockerfile ended up looking something like this:

```
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
COPY package*.json ./

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

#Copy all necessary files for runtime, including configurations
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/utils ./utils
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```